# Async WebSocket JS Class

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

//Client.js

```
var CON,FUNC;
class FUNCS {
  constructor() {}
   async createAccount(coinId){
    await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      CON.openAccount(coinId).then(response => {
        console.log(response); //returns undefined
        resolve(response);
      })
    });
  }
}
class CONNECTION {   
  constructor() {this.socket = io.connect()}
   async openAccount(id){
   await Promise.resolve(this.socket.emit('openAccount',{'id':id},function (rs) { 
      return rs;
    }));
  }
}
CON = new CONNECTION(),FUNC = new FUNCS();
```

//index.html

```
<span onClick="FUNC.createAccount()"></span>
```

app.js

```
socket.on('openAccount',function (id,fn) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        fn('seee');
    },3000)
});
```

how can i catch callback from app.js in FUNCS.createAccount's console
Because its giving undefined

```
CON.openAccount(coinId).then(response => {   
  **console.log(response);//returns undefined;**
  resolve(response);
})
```

Comment: Why are you using uppercase for class, variable and methods? Any particular reason?

Comment: it's a kind of habit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's keep the code style out of the discussion and have a look at the `openAccount` method:

- If you are willing to grab something out of your method you need to return something. As it is defined, `openAccount` returns `undefined` (It's just waiting for the anonymous Promise and then returns nothing)
- Even returning the promise (as expected by the `await` construct) would not work here, because it actually resolves the result of the socketIo `emit` method which returns `undefined` as well (because it is built to work with a callback)

Here is a simplified working exemple where socketIo is put appart and replaced by `setTimeout`:

```js
async function resolveIfNumber(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => Number(x) === x ? resolve(x) : reject("not a number"))
  })
}

resolveIfNumber("1").then(console.log, console.error)
// console.error("not a number")
resolveIfNumber(1).then(console.log, console.error)
// console.log(1)
```

You might want to read [this quick introduction to the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for further explanation

Comment: Thanks for your answer; i saw many example about async/await but, i found its not working in socket.io emit  

await Promise.resolve(this.socket.emit('openAccount',{'id':id},function (rs) { 
      return rs;
    }));

how can i solve this with async system

Comment: As stated in the answer your `openAccount` method should look more like this:

`return new Promise((resolve) => this.socket.emit('openAccount', { id }, rs => resolve(rs))`

Answer (score 0):

i solved

//FUNC's Class

```
async createAccount(id){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    CON.openAccount(id).then(response => {
      console.log(response); //returns response
      resolve(response);
    })
  });
}
```

//CONNECTION's Class

```
async openAccount(id){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.socket.emit('openAccount',{'id':id},function (rs) {
        resolve(rs);
    })
  })
}
```